# Generating a machine code using SPIM

Tags: hexdump, spim

I have to do an assignment which consists of developing a simulator for MIPS instructions.
To test this simulator I need as inputs a code machine or a hedump code of an assembly file.
I tried to use SPIM on Linux but when I check the help menu I can t find the way to generate these kind of files.
Any suggestions or answers would be very appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try this link it gonna help your needs for now, It always good to write your own test file
https://github.com/eliottwiener/MIPS-Simulator/blob/master/test.hexdump

Comment: thanks for the reply. but my main concern is to have a tool to generate the hexdump file from a MIPS assembly code. Do you have any idea on how can i use for example SPIM to generate the hexdump file ?